# Customize permalink wordpress category id

Tags: plugins, php, functions, permalinks, categories

I'm looking to add "ID" for tags And category in the URL permalink.

Our link right now is:

```
example.com/lastnews
example.com/hashtag/{tagname}
```

We looking to change it to:

```
example.com/{cat-id}/lastnews
example.com/hashtag/{tag-id}/{tagname}
```

Can any one help us to do that any code,plugin?

Comment: Maybe the code shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6175103) helps you to achieve at least the cat_id wish.